# C# Obtener, utilizando linq, los elementos de un documento XML que tengan algún atributo cuyo valor coincida con un literal particular

Tags: c#, xml, linq

De un Xml quiero obtener los elementos donde el valor de cualquier atributo es igual al "rId4".
Intenté la siguiente expresión con Xml.Linq en lenguaje C#

```
var decendants = XDocument.Load("//myfile.xml").Descendants();
var blips = from attr in decendants
            where attr.Attribute("*").Value == "rId4"
            select attr;
```

pero me dice lo siguiente

> Un nombre no puede empezar con el caracter '*', valor hexadecimal 0x2A.

pongo el valor "*" para que me haga match con cualquier atributo donde su valor sea "rId4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que lo estas tratando de hacer te da error porque el valor que espera el método `Attribute` de la class `XElement` (que es a la que se instancia la variable `attr` en tu codigo) es el nombre del atributo, y no una expresion `XPath`, como la que estas intentando utilizar (en este caso `*` para tratar de obtener todos los atributos).

Deberías utilizar el método `Attributes()` que retorna todos los atrributos del elemento inspeccionado, y de estos tomar cualquiera  (usando `Any`) que cumpla el predicado de igualdad sobre la propiedad `Value`. El codigo sería algo como el que sigue, en el cual la comparación con el operador `==` es case-sensitive

(El código incluye un xml de prueba cargado desde una cadena)

```
//Carga desde una cadena el cuerpo del documento
var s  = "<root><a a1=\"rId4\"/><b><c c1=\"rId4\" /></b></root>";
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
var d = XDocument.Load(ms).Descendants();

var b = from element in d
        where element.Attributes().Any( attr => attr.Value=="rId4" )
        select element;

foreach(var itemx in b.ToArray()) {
    Console.WriteLine(itemx.Name);
}
```